# Interface slice to uint64 slice

Tags: golang

Можно ли прокастить слайс интерфейсов в слайс uint64 без итераций и аллокации нового среза uint64 ?

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Интерфейсные значения по сути являются структурами из двух указателей: на данные и на информацию о типе. Данные могут быть разбросаны по всей памяти, так что без аллокации вы их не соберёте.